# How to compare previous mongodb aggregation's result document's two arrays of objects by a field and get a final array?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-atlas

I have done a few pipeline stages to get a document like:

```
{
allDatesInitialCompletedTimes: [
{date: '2023-07-09T18:00:00.000Z', localDate: '2023-07-10', completedTime: 0},
{date: '2023-07-10T18:00:00.000Z', localDate: '2023-07-11', completedTime: 0}, 
{date: '2023-07-11T18:00:00.000Z', localDate: '2023-07-12', completedTime: 0},
{date: '2023-07-12T18:00:00.000Z', localDate: '2023-07-13', completedTime: 0},
{date: '2023-07-13T18:00:00.000Z', localDate: '2023-07-14', completedTime: 0},
{date: '2023-07-14T18:00:00.000Z', localDate: '2023-07-15', completedTime: 0},
{date: '2023-07-15T18:00:00.000Z', localDate: '2023-07-16', completedTime: 0}
],
existingDatesCompletedTimes: [
{date: '2023-07-12T23:26:52.015Z', localDate: '2023-07-13', completedTime: 179140}, 
{date: '2023-07-12T00:41:58.208Z', localDate: '2023-07-12', completedTime: 393575},
{date: '2023-07-11T05:14:39.234Z', localDate: '2023-07-11', completedTime: 49076},
{date: '2023-07-15T01:16:24.766Z', localDate: '2023-07-15', completedTime: 298040},
{date: '2023-07-14T01:08:24.053Z', localDate: '2023-07-14', completedTime: 1512468}
]
}
```

You can see "allDatesInitialCompletedTimes" has all the localDates and initial completedTimes for them.

On the other hand, "existingDatesCompletedTimes" doesn't have two localDates '2023-07-10' and '2023-07-16'

Now, I want `allDatesInitialCompletedTimes` array's every object's `localDate` to compare with `existingDatesCompletedTimes` array's every object's `localDate`.

If `allDatesInitialCompletedTimes` any object's `localDate` is **found** in `existingDatesCompletedTimes` array's any object, I want to replace the object in `allDatesInitialCompletedTimes` with object in `existingDatesCompletedTimes`.

If `allDatesInitialCompletedTimes` any object's `localDate` is **not found** in `existingDatesCompletedTimes` array's any object, I want to keep the object in `allDatesInitialCompletedTimes` intact.

Expected final array in a document:

```
{ allDatesCompletedTimes: [
>! this localDate is not found in `existingDatesCompletedTimes`
{date: '2023-07-09T18:00:00.000Z', localDate: '2023-07-10', completedTime: 0},
>! but, this localDate is found in `existingDatesCompletedTimes` 
{date: '2023-07-11T05:14:39.234Z', localDate: '2023-07-11', completedTime: 49076},
{date: '2023-07-12T00:41:58.208Z', localDate: '2023-07-12', completedTime: 393575},
{date: '2023-07-12T23:26:52.015Z', localDate: '2023-07-13', completedTime: 179140},
{date: '2023-07-14T01:08:24.053Z', localDate: '2023-07-14', completedTime: 1512468},
{date: '2023-07-15T01:16:24.766Z', localDate: '2023-07-15', completedTime: 298040},
{date: '2023-07-15T18:00:00.000Z', localDate: '2023-07-16', completedTime: 0}
]}
```

Comment: Sounds like this could be done via `$map`, `$cond`, and some additional array expression operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option, as @user20042973 mentioned, is:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {
      allDatesInitialCompletedTimes: {$map: {
          input: "$allDatesInitialCompletedTimes",
          in: {$cond: [
              {$in: ["$$this.localDate", "$existingDatesCompletedTimes.localDate"]},
              {$arrayElemAt: [
                  "$existingDatesCompletedTimes",
                  {$indexOfArray: [
                      "$existingDatesCompletedTimes.localDate",
                      "$$this.localDate"
                  ]}
              ]},
              "$$this"
          ]}
      }}
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RwtE5inC46s)